# Returning inside for loop inside lambda crashes in Ruby 1.8

Tags: ruby, lambda, for-loop, return

In Ruby 1.8 (my version is 1.8.7-72), this code:

```
foo = lambda do
  for j in 1..2
    return
  end
end
foo.call
```

crashes with a `LocalJumpError`:

```
test2.rb:3: unexpected return (LocalJumpError)
    from test2.rb:2:in `each'
    from test2.rb:2
    from test2.rb:6:in `call'
    from test2.rb:6
```

Why does it do this? However, it seems to run fine on my version of Ruby 1.9.

**Edit:** it's not just the returning inside a lambda; the following runs fine:

```
foo = lambda do
  return
end
foo.call
```

Answer (score 8):

What's happening is that the for statement in the middle of the lambda is converted internally into a block. In Ruby, return statements inside blocks are scoped to their enclosing method. Consider the following:

```
def bar
  foo = lambda do
    for j in 1..2
      return j
    end
  end
  foo[]
end
p bar
```

When running `bar`, `1` is returned, because the `return` is scoped to the entire `bar` method. To return from blocks, you want to use `next` or `break`, both of which take parameters. Consider:

```
def bar
  foo = lambda do
    for j in 1..2
      break j
    end
  end
  foo[] + 1
end
p bar
```

This break returns you from the block, and blocks any subsequent iterations. In this case, calling `bar` would return `2`, since the iterator will return `1`, and `foo[] + 1` will therefore return `2`.

If all of that sounded confusing, the main thing to realize is that return inside blocks is scoped to a surrounding method, and absent a surrounding method, a `LocalJumpError` is raised.

Comment: why can't it scope to the lambda instead? I can't simply break out of the loop, because in my original scenario, there is code after the for loop which I need to skip

Comment: You could try using a real method, rather than a lambda.

Comment: Damn. Ruby 1.8 won't allow return from inside a proc from inside a method defined via define_method. Scratch that.

Answer (score 0):

you can escape the loop and the rest of the lambda with a throw/catch

```
foo = lambda do 
        catch(:escape) do
          for j in 1..2
            throw :escape
          end
          # other code that won't get run
        end # catch(:escape)
      end # lambda
```

`throw` also takes an optional second paramter, which you can use to return a value.

Comment: This is a pretty heavyweight solution to emulate a return, I think.

Comment: there aren't a lot of other options wrt to _emulating_ a return (the other options being exceptions and callcc). I suspect of the choices it is the lightest weight. The best solution is probably just use a method, but this can be awkward if the scope you need to close over doesn't lend itself well to that. This is why 1.9 letting you return from lambda's is nice.

Comment: I added a way to emulate Ruby 1.9 lambdas in Ruby 1.8 in my answer, which would be more lightweight than throw/catch.

Comment: Hmm. I tried that approach, I didn't quite get it to work. I'm no doubt rusty.

Comment: Nah. Ruby 1.8 is old and busted and it won't work :( I reverted my change.